# Redirect landing page to login page if not logged in (tanyacms)

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, content-management-system

It's my first question in Stack. I hope to be helped out.

I am working on a Q&A portal for my country. I am using Tanya CMS, it's pretty good.

But I want visitors to land in log in page, if they are not logged in. I believe there could be some if statement to do the job but I have no knowledge of PHP and I am a newbie.

my index.php file is;

```
<?php
/*
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   TanyaCMS - Question and Answer Sofware
|   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   by fbschool dev team
|   (c) 2011 - 2012 FBSCHOOL
|   http://www.fbschool.com/tanyacms
|   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   This is NOT a freeware, use is subject to license terms
|   Support: 13455n@gmail.com
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
*/

if (! file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/system/config/database.php') AND 
! file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/system/config/install.lock.php'))
{
header('Location: ./install/');
exit;
}

include('system/system.php');

ASK_APP::run();
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the login code in front of everything else. So no matter which URL they access, they will see the login first, if they haven't logged in yet. No need for a redirect that would only make it more difficult to send them back to where they originally wanted to be.

Comment: would you please show me how to? i am sorry but seriously, i have no idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know Tanya CMS. That was a very high level answer.

Answer (score 0):

in php there is a session-variable ($_SESSION) which each web user has and which can hold state for each users' session.

you can use the information stored in the users session-variable ($_SESSION) to check if the user is logged in.